# GParted for one partition

Tags: gparted

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLJmu.jpg
I have one partition as in picture above. I want to create 50GB of partition to install Windows. How can I do that? Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't resize the root partition.

If I were you, I'll Backup my data and try GParted with Live CD.

Kindly notice that you don't have a swap area.